# WSO2 unable to logon with new user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a new production instance of WSO2. When I add a new user through the console of the Identity Server, it is added and I can see in users list and in the SQL DB. However I am unable to log on to IS with this user name. The only err is:

```
TID: [0] [IS] [2015-12-28 09:39:50,292]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'txritter[-1234]' at [2015-12-28 09:39:50,291-0500] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

Any ideas appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. When creating a new user in WSO2 console, it shows the internal/subscriber role as selected but after adding the user the role is not selected. Selecting this role and updating user allows new user to log on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. When creating a new user in WSO2 console, it shows the internal/subscriber role as selected but after adding the user the role is not selected. Selecting this role and updating user allows new user to log on. We are using version 5.0.